# SQL query to map data elements across columns in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, mapping

I have a 3 column table, and some columns have the same attributes. I want to return a table that shows which columns each attribute appears in. I am using SQL in Microsoft Access for this. How can I do this? Just an idea of where to start would be helpful as I do not have much SQL experience.

Table I have:

| fruits1 | fruits2 | fruits3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | banana | lemon |
| banana | cherry | grape |
| lemon | apple | mango |
| orange | grape | banana |

Table I want to return:

[image]

So far I have been doing this manually, and it is not working as the tables I am working with hold large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some VBA to do this. Something like:

```
Sub sUnpivot()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSteer As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsLookup As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
' Start by getting a unique list across the 3 columns
    strSQL = "SELECT Fruits1 AS Fruits FROM tblPivot " _
        & " UNION SELECT Fruits2 FROM tblPivot " _
        & " UNION SELECT Fruits3 FROM tblPivot;"
    Set rsSteer = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsSteer.BOF And rsSteer.EOF) Then
        db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblUnpivot;"    ' get rid of old data
        Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblUnpivot WHERE 1=2;")
        Do
            With rsData
                .AddNew
                !Attribute = rsSteer!Fruits
                strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPivot WHERE Fruits1='" & rsSteer!Fruits & "';"
                Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
                If rsLookup(0) > 0 Then !Fruits1 = "x"
                strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPivot WHERE Fruits2='" & rsSteer!Fruits & "';"
                Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
                If rsLookup(0) > 0 Then !Fruits2 = "x"
                strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPivot WHERE Fruits3='" & rsSteer!Fruits & "';"
                Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
                If rsLookup(0) > 0 Then !Fruits3 = "x"
                .Update
            End With
            rsSteer.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsSteer.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsLookup.Close
    rsSteer.Close
    rsData.Close
    Set rsLookup = Nothing
    Set rsSteer = Nothing
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vvbcrlf & vbCrLf & "sUnpivot", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```